# OneSignal hello-world webpage - no notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I've spent an embarrassingly long time on this seemingly incredibly easy problem with 0 progress. I'm pretty desperate at this point, so if anybody could review the short example I've written, I would greatly appreciate it.

What I'm trying to do: send a push notification using OneSignal's Web Push SDK.

Files in `~/Desktop/OneSignal-Browser-Example`:

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <title>OneSignal Example</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async></script>
    <script>
        var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
        OneSignal.push(["init", {
          appId: "518e60ef-8b73-4852-8172-61cb170dce00",
          autoRegister: true,
          notifyButton: {
            enable: true /* Set to false to hide */
          }
        }]);
        console.log("Test");
    </script>
    <h1>LOADED</h1>
</head>
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "OneSignal Example",
  "short_name": "OneSignalExample",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "gcm_sender_id": "482941778795"
}
```

**OneSignalSDKWorker.js**

```
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js');
```

**OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js**

```
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js');
```

**cert.pem**

**key.pem**

I launched Google Chrome with `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-certificate-errors`, and set up a https server on port 8081 with `http-server --ssl --p 8081 ~/Desktop/OneSignal-Browser-Example`.

Attached is a screenshot of the trace log.

[image: trace log image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we were able to help you out over our support channel to solve the issue.

The issue was a specific configuration mismatch: uPaymeiFixit had modified the `manifest.json` file's `gcm_sender_id` property to an incorrect value; he subscribed after this change and registered his user with a mismatched GCM Sender ID which prevented notifications from being able to send even though everything else was correct.

The solution to this issue was to:

1. [Correct](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/website-sdk-installation#2-upload-required-files) the `gcm_sender_id` value.
2. [Reset his site data and cache](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/website-push-common-problems#clearing-your-cache-and-resetting-push-permissions) to test again as a new user.

He was able to receive a notification right after these changes.

Comment: #2 is the important one here